# NullPointerException in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

**Code:**

```
package com.example.shrine;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class products_act extends AppCompatActivity {
    String title[];
    String description[];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_products_act);
        title=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pro_title);
        description=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pro_desc);
        RecyclerView recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerr);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ProductsAdapter PA=new ProductsAdapter(this,title,description);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(PA);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings,menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Adapter class:**

```
package com.example.shrine;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class ProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.ProViewHolder> {
    Context ct;
    String[] data1;
    String[] data2;
    public ProductsAdapter(Context context,String title[],String description[]){
        ct=context;
        data1=title;
        data2=description;
    }


    public class ProViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView head;
        TextView info;
        ImageView pro_img;
        public ProViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            head=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            info=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            pro_img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View layoutview= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_products_act,parent,false);
        return new ProViewHolder(layoutview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.head.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.info.setText(data2[position]);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data1.length;
    }


}
```

**ERROR:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.shrine, PID: 4610
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shrine/com.example.shrine.products_act}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.shrine.products_act.onCreate(products_act.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Please resolve this issue and also please explain why NullPointerException occurs so that I can resolve these kind of problems myself in future.Explain  NullPointerException in brief in relation with android.
Also if possible please do state some points to keep in mind everytime while dealing with RecyclerView.

Comment: You have a null pointer exception because your pointer is null.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your recycler id in this line RecyclerView `recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerr);`. Check if it's correspond of what you have in your activity_products_act.xml file